# Rsync does not delete destination files [rsync protocol / module]

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, linux-networking, deleting

An automatic backup script executes the following `rsync` command to sync a local directory tree with a remote one:

```
env RSYNC_PASSWORD=$rsync_password rsync -aqrxz --delete --timeout=30 \
    "${rsync_username}"@"${rsync_host}"::"${rsync_module}" ./ \
    --exclude /$(basename "$0") --exclude /config/local_host.sh --exclude /local
```

Files and directories are copied / updated / created into the target host, however, they are not deleted from target if they cease to exist in source. That is, the command above is able to only create and update files and directories from source to target, but not to delete them.

On the target host, `rsync` is executed by the user `www-data`, and the whole target directory tree is owned by `www-data` with 755 permissions.

On the source host, `rsync` is executed as a root daemon thru the rsync protocol.

Comment: Which is the module configuration? does it have settings against delete options (ie refuse options)?